# Spring Transaction Management using aspectj

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, aspectj

Have 2 configuration files in a project. Both having Transaction management for different datasources using aspectj as follows-

context1.xml

```
<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<!-- MySQL DB DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
    <property name="username" value="t" />
    <property name="password" value="t123" />
</bean>
```

context2. xml

```
<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>

<!-- MySQL DB DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB2" />
    <property name="username" value="t2" />
    <property name="password" value="t2123" />
</bean>
```

This causes setting of transactionManager property of Abstract class - 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport to the last annotation transaction aspect bean created during server startup.

**Thus if the last bean instantiated is of dataSource1, the transactions are created on dataSource1, else for dataSource2.**
How can this issue be resolved?

in a DAO class for TransactionManagement use transaction as follows-

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor =   customException.class)
@Override
public void addDoc(param doc) throws customException{

    addOrUpdate(testQuery, doc, "add new doc");
}
```

Instead of @transactional("tansactionManager2"), @transactional for transactionManager2 is used only at 2 places. Can we implement **non AOP implement of transaction** for these methods so that there are not many changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use qualifiers to indicate the transaction manager to be used:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    <qualifier value="transactionManager1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <qualifier value="transactionManager2"/>
</bean>
```

and annotate your service methods with `@Transactional("transactionManager1")` or `@Transactional("transactionManager2")`.

For more details on how to define multiple transaction managers see [Spring DOC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)